# QtCreator - autocomplete does not include parameters, ie overriding void paintEvent(....)

Tags: c++, qt

When I press ENTER to autocomplete methods, QtCreator never includes the parameters.

One example is this:

```
protected:
      void paintEvent();
```

which should be this:

```
protected:
      void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
```

I never seem to get the parameters when I press CTRL+SPACE, and then ENTER.

This is "ok" when I have one parameter to add, but when there are multiple I have to add  manually, the typing gets quite tedious.

Anyone knows what's going on? I've seen multiple videos on youtube where the author pressed some keys (afaik) and all the parameters where added in his overriding methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QtCreator 3.1.1 this works perfectly if i start writing -> then do autocompletion of the method -> then press Enter and then press TAB.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, instead of enter I press TAB twice. :) 
In other words: CTRL-SPACE to get the autocomplete going, then pressing tab twice :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put text cursor at the class name in the beginning of class declaration, press Alt+Enter and select "Insert virtual functions of base classes". You will be able to select which functions you want to add and where to place function implementation body.

See [Refactoring](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-3.1/creator-editor-refactoring.html) in QtCreator manual.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. It seems that every time I write out the complete method name and then press the '(' (paranthesis) - it adds the variables.

If I don't write out the complete method-name it won't suggest any parameters whenever I press ENTER.